# Infinite grow of SST files number for stateful Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

We are running a very straightforward Apache Spark Streaming application on Databricks. It consumes messages from Apache Kafka, does a deduplication based on a 1-hour watermark, and writes the output as JSON files.

Previously, we used an HDFS-backed state store provider with storing deduplication state on S3. The size of the checkpoint storage was more or less stable. But with this solution, we struggle with the issue when, after some time, the job occasionally fails due to OOM. And we decided to switch to the RocksDB state store provider.

It looks like the OOM issue is gone, but we noticed that our state store location currently contains ~1.6 million files with a total size of ~5 GB, and the number of files constantly grows. During the investigation, it was discovered that most files are SST files. This concerns us because, in case of a need to restart the streaming from some specific point, for example, to recover the failure, we have to spend a lot of time removing a ton of tiny files from S3 before starting our app.

Is this infinitely growing number of SST files expected for Spark Streaming applications? Is there any way to compact them or clean them up?

Answer (score 0):

State files should be cleaned up.  I believe 100 microbatches worth of state files are kept around.  Double check the compute resources have the ability to remove files at the checkpoint directory.

Comment: Our cluster has RW access to the bucket and technically can remove stale files, but as I describe, the number of files continuously grows. We also don't have any exceptions logged. Do you know if it is possible to enable extra logging to check if the job tries to cleanup the state store?

Comment: Check the driver log.  It should have the file deletion info i believe.  Make sure the log level is INFO.